# Gif loading in LazyColum using io.coil-k, During recompose it does not load gif immediately

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

Below is my configuration for the coil imaging loader for the gif loading.

```
val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context).
        memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED).
        diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .components {
            if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                add(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
            } else {
                add(GifDecoder.Factory())
            }
        }.diskCache(
            DiskCache.Builder()
                .directory(context.cacheDir.resolve("image_cache"))
                .maxSizePercent(0.50)
                .build()).memoryCache( MemoryCache.Builder(context)
            .maxSizePercent(0.50)
            .build())
        .build()
```

Here is my compose code.

```
val imageData = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(original.url)
            .size(Size.ORIGINAL) // Set the target size to load the image at.
            .build()


    SubcomposeAsyncImage(
        model = imageData,contentDescription = gifItem.title,
        imageLoader = value,
        loading = {
            // Display a loading indicator while the GIF is loading
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        },
        success = { state ->
            // Display the GIF image
            Image(
                painter = state.painter,
                contentDescription = "GIF Image",
                alignment = Alignment.Center,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            )
        },
        error = {
            // Display an error message if the GIF image could not be loaded
        }
    )
```

See the result below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my answer from here https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/discussions/1175

I just need to configure ImageLoader like below.

```
val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .respectCacheHeaders(false)
        .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED).
        diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .components {
            if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                add(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
            } else {
                add(GifDecoder.Factory())
            }
        }.diskCache(
            DiskCache.Builder()
                .directory(context.cacheDir.resolve("image_cache"))
                .maxSizePercent(0.50)
                .build()).memoryCache( MemoryCache.Builder(context)
            .maxSizePercent(0.50)
            .build())
        .build()
```

Main change is `respectCacheHeaders(false)` need to set as false.